# Which widget(mainly panel) can i use for auto scaling in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am using absolute panel in gwt application according to my window screen.but i want to use a panel which is auto scalable or adjustable according to client window screen. so is it possible or any panel which position relatively rather than absolutely?

Thanks 
rahul

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (SplitLayoutPanel):

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSplitLayoutPanel

Answer (score 0):

SplitLayoutPanel and DockLayoutPanel are great but they are limitated as they just extends LayoutPanel.

I would recommend to get used of LayoutPanel as it is more flexible for anny liquid layout you have in mind.

In pseudocode, you just need to.

Define your Widget x;

Define your LayoutPanel lp.

add the widget in lp. (lp.add(x)) this will just enlarge your widget to fit All the screen as you have not defined any constrain yet.

you can then apply constrains combined as you want. (BOTTOM; TOP; LEFT; RIGHT; WIDTH; HEIGHT;)

For example: TOP and WIDTH constrains:

lp.setWidgetTopWidth (the widget, the TOP position, the TOP unit, the WIDTH of the widget, the WIDTH unit).

Here, the UNIT is quite important. If you choose PX. Your application will *NOT* be liquid. As it will be static across different screens. In our company we have 16:9 and 4:3 screens. So we use PCT unit (percentage) for WIDTH contrains but we use PX for TOP (our header is the same for all the screens).

You can even apply EM unit to a dimension if you want your widget to get bigger if the user zoom in or zoom out your application.

Annother beneffit of using LayoutPanel is changing the layout on runtime. You can easily fit a second widget (and a third, fourth, ... ) by reducing the space dedicated to the others and then adding and applying constrains to the new one.

hope this helps you as it helped us!

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LayoutPanel.html